# Validate across nested serializers with django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

If you were to have a nested serializer, but required a certain parameter in the parent depending on a value in the child, how could you enforce the logical requirement when necessary?

For example:

```
class ChildSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     foobar_attribute = serializers.ChoiceField(
         required=True,
         choices=foobar_choices,
     )



class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     child = ChildSerializer(required=True)

     optional_attribute = serializers.CharField(
         required=False,
     )
```

`optional_attribute` should be required only when `foobar_attribute` is a certain choice, but optional for all else. Throwing a `validate` function on `ParentSerializer` or `ChildSerializer` only exposes attributes for that serializer, and none else.

How can I perform validation across nested serializers without creating rows ( as would occur if validation was performed in `perform_create` )?

Comment: have you tried to override the **`validate`** method of `ParentSerializer` ?

Comment: Yes, the values of the child are not surfaced with `validate` on the parent

Comment: can you add the validate method that you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite the `__init__` function

```
def __init__(self, instance=None, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(instance, *args, **kwargs)
    if your_condition:
        self.fields['optional_attribute'].required = True
```

You can also change any attribute of the `optional_attribute` field

Comment: `your_condition` is something should fetch from the input data

Comment: valid one. IMHO, it's better to implement *validation logic* inside the validators or something similar